# Storing an integer counter in indexer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been implementing a custom internal server error page in ASP.Net MVC which will check if the current user is either an administrator or accessing the page from localhost, and if so, show them a whole bunch of details about the error to debug it with, otherwise just send them to a basic HTML error page.

So far, it works great, but one problem I had was that if there is an error in a partial view on the page, the system gets stuck in a loop trying to report the error.

To avoid this, I'm storing a temporary counter of how many times the current action has requested the error page in [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), but I find the amount of lines and style of the code to get, set and check this variable a bit verbose:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        [ActionName("500")]
        public ActionResult InternalServerError(string aspxerrorpath = null)
        {
            int detectRedirectLoop = (TempData.Peek("redirectLoop") as int?) ?? 0;
            TempData["redirectLoop"] = detectRedirectLoop + 1;
            if((int) TempData.Peek("redirectLoop") <= 1)
            {
                // Check if user is admin or running locally and display error if so
            }
            return Redirect("/GeneralError.htm");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better/prettier/shorter way of doing this?

Comment: One obvious problem: `"redirectLoop"` is repeated three times, and should obviously be a `const`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private const string RedirectLoopCounterName = "RedirectLoopCounter";
    private const int MaxRedirectLoopCount = 1;

    private int RedirectLoopCounter
    {
        get { return ((int?)TempData.Peek(RedirectLoopCounterName)) ?? 0; }
        set { TempData[RedirectLoopCounterName] = value; }
    }

    private int IncreaseRedirectLoopCounter() 
    {
        return ++RedirectLoopCounter;
    }

    [ActionName("500")]
    public ActionResult InternalServerError(string aspxerrorpath = null)
    {       
        var isRedirectLoop = IncreaseRedirectLoopCounter() > MaxRedirectLoopCount;
        if(isRedirectLoop)
        {
            return Redirect("/GeneralError.htm");
        }

        // Check if user is admin or running locally and display error if so
    }
}
```

- Create a constant for the counter's name as already mentioned by @BCdotWEB
- Create a property for getting and setting its value
- Create a method for actually increasing the counters value
- Additionaly you could replace the `1` by a constant
- Finally you can replace the condition by a helper variable to document it better
- I would also invert the `if`

Comment: oh, I was't sure about that but it shouldn't be a problem to change it ;-)

Comment: I removed the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I have serious concerns about your use of TempData here: http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

My problem is it assumes your resource requests are single threaded (on a per-client basis), so if you have a client attempting to access more than one resource simultaneously I *think* your counter gets thrown off.

From my reading of that link I posted it wouldn't know if a subsequent request was in parallel or sequence to your initial 500.

Comment: `Therefore, the only scenario where using TempData will reliably work is when you are redirecting` that is happening in this case, as all uncaught exceptions redirect the user to `error/500` (the webserver does this), and if the exception is also thrown on (part of) the error page, the user gets redirected again to `error/500`. Before I added the loop counter, this problem would cause a `this page is not redirecting properly` error in the browser after 30 or so redirects to the same page. +1 for giving me something to test though.